# php publish video to facebook wall

Tags: php, curl, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to create an app that will upload & publish a video to user's wall.
following the api docs there are no examples of publishing

[https://developers.facebook.com/…/reference/v2.2/user/videos](https://developers.facebook.com/%E2%80%A6/reference/v2.2/user/videos)

I've looked up for similar questions in here but they're all old referring to fb api.

the API returns a message that I should use curl, when I'm using curl 
it returns false.

is there any php example of publishing video?

example of my code:

```
$url = 'https://graph-video.facebook.com/me/videos';
$cfile = new CURLFile('test.mp4','video/mp4','video');

$post_params = array(
            'title' => "myTitle",
            'name' => "blahblah",
            'source' => $cfile,
            'access_token' => $token    
       );
$ch = curl_init();

    //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data 
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: multipart/form-data"));

   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_params);
   //execute post 
   $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer for that using FB API & CURLFile, hope it would help someone else

```
   $url = 'https://graph-video.facebook.com/me/videos';

   $cfile = new CURLFile(realpath('test.flv'),'video/x-flv');

   $movie_data = array('file' => $cfile);

   $post_params = array(
      'title' => "ffff",
       'name' => "tablished businesses”",
       'source' => $cfile,
       'access_token' => $token    
   );

   $request = new FacebookRequest(
              $session,
              'POST',
              '/me/videos',
              $post_params
            );



   $response = $request->execute();
```

the $response contains the id of the video.

enjoy